# Which design pattern to use for sequential actions and Retries

Tags: oop, design-patterns

There is a use case, where a message is created.

The message will be be processed sequentially by different functions until it reaches terminal status.

After each function has processed the status of the message is updated to track the progress. If for any scenario, there is a system issue and we want to retry the same message, then it should start of where it left off based on the status.

Which is the better design pattern to use. State machine or Chain of responsibility. Is there any other pattern which can be recommended for this scenario.

A crude example:

Message (Created with New Status) ----> Function1 Prcoessing --> Message (Status updated to FUNC1COMPLETE) --> etc... till it reachers terminal status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the transformations you're applying to messages is static and shouldn't change (at least not too much) then sounds that state-machine is good enough solution and probably more straightforward and easier to implement and maintain.

But if, on the other hand, you'll either need to create multiple such flows or your flow will change often and you want to be able to support changing it by configuration without modifying code, then Chain of responsibility should be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Even so, [State](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state) and [Chain of Responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) (`CoR`) are both behavioral patters, there are some differences between them. Both of them links many handlers but `CoR` is more straightforward. When you process given message with `CoR` you expect it will success or fail but you do not expect it will be repeated. Probably, the most natural implementation of `CoR` is used to handle `HTTP` request. You can successfully handle it or fail but cannot repeat it. In that case you need to generate new request on client side and invoke whole chain again.

From other side, state machine, can naturally direct from one handler to other and from one handler to itself. You can create many start points for your machine or one custom (`dispatcher`) which will read previous status and dispatch handling to most appropriate handler.

In your case, I recommend, to use `State` design pattern which fits better in this scenario.

For more information, I suggest, to read linked articles and take a look at:

- [Spring Statemachine](https://projects.spring.io/spring-statemachine/)
- [Spring Batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch)

projects for more inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to be able to route messages to the next handler based on their status, then you should *always* route messages based on their status, so their is no ambiguity about that decision.

Call the status a "state" and you have a state machine.  More generally, you can have a mapping function that determines the next handler based on the message type, contents, status, etc.